# How to make entire background image responsively fit into Jumbotron

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, background, background-image

I've researched and tried dozens of variations and am trying to figure out how to code it in Bootstrap 4, so that the entire image (native 1440 x 380) is visible in the jumbotron with the aspect ratio always maintained. At widths greater than 1440, the image needs to expand, i.e., 1600 x 422. Here's what I have so far, but I can't get the jumbotron to recognize the height of the image. Any suggestions?

HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid p-0">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="overlay"></div>
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
              Content
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
              More content
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
  .jumbotron {
    border-radius: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    min-height: 365px;
    background: url(hero_image.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
  }
```

Comment: Do you need to bg image to be stretched (in both height and width) to `.jumbotron`?

Comment: @PanwenWang - Yes, that's the request I've gotten from the client. They want the entire image to be visible at all sizes. I explained that on a mobile device, we'd likely have to have a min-height.

Comment: Then you must have some space in the container if it has a different aspect ratio as the image does. Is that correct? For example, if your image is 10x10, and your container is 10x20, then you may have 10 whitespace in height that is not covered by the image.

Comment: I need to make the jumbotron always match the size of the image. The problem I'm having is that the bottom of the image is not visible on most devices. They want the entire image to be visible, which means the height of the jumbotron needs to be increased.

Comment: Then `.jumbotron` has to have the same aspect ratio. You probably need some `javascript` to adjust it.

Comment: @PanwenWang - Doesn't the jumbotron adjust vertically to whatever content is inside it?

Comment: Not for background image.